# Dynamic way to unbind dynamically binded XBL

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, xbl

I am applying a binding like this in a restartless add-on:

```
var css = '.findbar-container { -moz-binding:url("' + self.path.chrome + 'findbar.xml#matchword") }';
var cssEnc = encodeURIComponent(css);
var newURIParam = {
    aURL: 'data:text/css,' + cssEnc,
    aOriginCharset: null,
    aBaseURI: null
}
cssUri = Services.io.newURI(newURIParam.aURL, newURIParam.aOriginCharset, newURIParam.aBaseURI);
myServices.sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(cssUri, myServices.sss.USER_SHEET);
```

`findbar.xml` contents are:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl" xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <binding id="matchword">
        <content>
            <children/>
            <xul:toolbarbutton anonid="matchwordbtn" accesskey="w" class="tabbable" label="Whole Word Only" tooltiptext="Match only whole words" oncommand="console.log('hi')" type="checkbox"/>
        </content>
    </binding>
</bindings>
```

This just adds a button to the `FindBar` labeled "Whole Word Only". But now to remove it, I am just unregistering the stylesheet with `myServices.sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, myServices.sss.USER_SHEET);`, however this is not unbinding it.

An [answer on ask.mozilla.org](https://ask.mozilla.org/question/297/apply-and-remove-xbl-binding-on-runtime/) told me this is expected behavior, but offered no solution.

I was thinking maybe I should dynamically add the binding rather than via CSS, I didn't test this but it doesn't fit the 3 reasons for XBL updates:

> 1. A bound element matches a style rule that specifies a different binding
> 2. The element is removed from the bound document
> 3. The element is destroyed (e.g., by closing the document)

The answer told me it's expected yet funky behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just remembered that I have some working code that does (re)bind different XBL bindings, essentially.

It goes like this:

- There is a base binding, or not (in your case the original binding of `.findbar-container`).
- Then I have multiple classes that define different `-moz-binding`s.
- These classes are set and removed at runtime.

Since that works for me, it should in theory work for you:

- In your style, do not have a rule for the element itself, but for a class, e.g.

  ```
  .findbar-container.myaddonclass { moz-binding: ... }
  ```
- In your code, on load add that new class, e.g.

  ```
  Array.forEach(
    document.querySelectorAll(".findbar-container"),
    e => e.classList.add("myaddonclass")
    );
  ```
- In your code, on unload remove the class again:

  ```
  Array.forEach(
    document.querySelectorAll(".findbar-container"),
    e => e.classList.remove("myaddonclass")
    );
  ```

This should force a CSS-rule reevaluation, and bindings reevaluation with that and hence fits the "A bound element matches a style rule that specifies a different binding" rule.

Of course, this sucks when not all elements you want to rebind are already present on load of your add-on, but [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) could help with that...

Comment: PS: Here is some code I use. [CSS rules (those `richlistitem` ones)](https://github.com/downthemall/anticontainer/blob/ac5d4e5119dc72cbeb2fe53e744ba84c05f386d8/skin/prefpane.css) and [corresponding bindings](https://github.com/downthemall/anticontainer/blob/ac5d4e5119dc72cbeb2fe53e744ba84c05f386d8/content/bindings.xml).

Comment: I was looking into this more, the reason I do `.findbar-container { moz-binding: ... }` is because findbar is seperate in all tabs now and it isnt initalized till the user does ctrl+f for first time in tab, so if i decide to add it with custom class, i have to listen and respond to initialize of findbar. so im looking for a method to trigger the xbl reflow, i tried setting dummy class names but that didnt trigger it, im trying to find a way right now. edit: oh i see you addressed that with MutationObserver, im trying to just iterate on shutdown to clear the binding from what has it attached