# Restartless add-on upgrade: reload XBL element in CustomizableUI widget

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, xbl

I've made a restartless add-on that is a `CustomizableUI` widget based on custom `XBL` elements. For an upcoming version I have altered the main `XBL` element `<slyzoom>`.

However, when I test the upgrade and inspect the markup with the DOM Inspector, the main `XBL` element is not refreshed in currently opened windows — only in newly opened windows the `XBL` element is expressed as intended.

I'm not entirely sure whether the problem lies with `CustomizableUI` not refreshing properly, or with the `XBL` bindings not refreshing properly.

And, although I don't have to restart Firefox, opening a new window for upgrade changes to take effect still kind of defeats the purpose of having a restartless add-on, for me.

[Another question, by Noitidart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403667/dynamic-way-to-unbind-dynamically-binded-xbl), seems to hint at a similar problem, although Noitidart seems to use a slightly different approach of loading bindings rules, so I'm not entirely sure my problem is exactly the same.

Can you shed a light on where the problem most likely lies?

My [`bootstrap.js`](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/files/browse/297874/file/bootstrap.js)<sup>1</sup> file is fairly involved, so I'll only put a simplified, slimmed down version here, with only `startup()` and `shutdown()` and with what I think are the most important aspects of getting it to work (see inline comments for additional commentary):

```js
const Cc = Components.classes;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;
const Cu = Components.utils;

const NSXUL            = 'http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul';
const URI_CSS_BINDINGS = 'chrome://slyzoom/content/bindings.css';

let ioService      = Cc[ '@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1' ].getService( Ci.nsIIOService );
let windowMediator = Cc[ '@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1' ].getService( Ci.nsIWindowMediator );

let styleSheetUri = ioService.newURI( URI_CSS_BINDINGS, null, null );

function startup( data, reason ) {

  let CustomizableUI = Cu.import( 'resource:///modules/CustomizableUI.jsm', {} ).CustomizableUI;

  // create the widget, this all works fine
  CustomizableUI.createWidget( {
    id: 'slyzoom',
    type: 'custom',
    defaultArea: null,
    onBuild: function( document ) {
      let window      = document.defaultView;
      let windowUtils = window.getInterface( Ci.nsIDOMWindowUtils );

      // load the XBL bindings stylesheet in the window where my widget is being build
      windowUtils.loadSheet( styleSheetUri, Ci.nsIDOMWindowUtils.AUTHOR_SHEET );

      let toolBarItemAttributes = {
        id: 'slyzoom',
        label: 'SlyZoom',
        title: 'SlyZoom',
        removable: 'true',
        overflows: false
      }
      let toolBarItem = document.createElementNS( NSXUL, 'toolbaritem' );
      let slyZoom     = document.createElementNS( NSXUL, 'slyzoom' );

      for( let attributeName in toolBarItemAttributes ) {
        toolBarItem.setAttribute( attributeName, toolBarItemAttributes[ attributeName ] );
      }
      toolBarItem.appendChild( slyZoom );

      let listener = {
        onWidgetInstanceRemoved: function( id, widgetDocument ) {
          if( id == this.id && widgetDocument == document ) {
            CustomizableUI.removeListener( listener );

            // unload the XBL bindings stylesheet from the window where my widget is being removed
            windowUtils.removeSheet( styleSheetUri, Ci.nsIDOMWindowUtils.AUTHOR_SHEET );
          }
        }.bind( this ),
      };
      CustomizableUI.addListener( listener );

      return toolBarItem;
    }
  } );
}


// I thought everything in here would be enough to force a reload in startup(), but apparently it isn't
function shutdown( data, reason ) {

  if( APP_SHUTDOWN == reason ) {
    return;
  }

  let CustomizableUI = Cu.import( 'resource:///modules/CustomizableUI.jsm', {} ).CustomizableUI;

  // I thought this would destroy any DOM instance of my widget/XBL elements
  // and it actually does; I know this because I log messages
  // in the destructor of the XBL elements,
  // but this doesn't seem to be enough
  CustomizableUI.destroyWidget( 'slyzoom' );

  // unload the XBL bindings stylesheet from the every navigator window;
  // this doesn't do the job I expected it to do either
  let domWindows = windowMediator.getEnumerator( 'navigator:browser' );
  while( domWindows.hasMoreElements() ) {
    let domWindow   = domWindows.getNext();
    let windowUtils = domWindow.getInterface( Ci.nsIDOMWindowUtils );
    windowUtils.removeSheet( styleSheetUri, Ci.nsIDOMWindowUtils.AUTHOR_SHEET );
  }
}
```

<sup>1) follow the link to view the complete version</sup>

Comment: The firfox-addon tag is the most important ones. The firefox-addon-restartless tag is redundant no one checks that, it should be merged to firefox-addon. I editted in the tag you should get more views now. Ill read this later too it looks like something i might be able to help with.

Comment: @Noitidart Thanks Noitidart! I appreciate any help I can get with this, cause with this one I'm not entirely sure where to look.

Comment: Yea man XBL errors are sometimes hard to debug cuz its so funky. Im a bit busy but Ill definitely try to get to this. :)

Comment: Thanks Noitidart! Take your time, of course. And yeah: XBL can get a bit complex. In the meanwhile, is the question of yours, that I mentioned in this question, related to this? Should I try to load XBL with css classes, for instance? Could that solve anything?